# Iterate over different dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, iterator

I am trying to iterate over three data frames to find the difference between them. I have a master data frame which contains everything and two other data frames which contains partial of master data frame. I am trying to write a python code to identify what is missing in the other two files. Master file looks like following:

```
ID  Name
1   Mike
2   Dani
3   Scott
4   Josh
5   Nate
6   Sandy
```

second data frame looks like following:

```
ID  Name
1   Mike
2   Dani
3   Scott
6   Sandy
```

Third data frame looks like following:

```
ID  Name
1   Mike
2   Dani
3   Scott
4   Josh
5   Nate
```

So there will be two output data frame. Desired output for looks like following for second data frame:

```
ID  Name
4   Josh
5   Nate
```

desired output for third data frame looks like following:

```
ID  Name
6   Sandy
```

I didn't find anything similar on Google. I tried this:

```
for i in second['ID'], third['ID']:
   if i not in master['ID']:
     print(i)
```

It returns all the data in master file.

Also if I try this code :

```
import pandas as pd

names = ["Mike", "Dani", "Scott", "Josh", "Nate", "Sandy"]
ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
master = pd.DataFrame({"ID": ids, "Name": names})
# print(master)

names_second = ["Mike", "Dani", "Scott", "Sandy"]
ids_second = [1, 2, 3, 6]
second = pd.DataFrame({"ID": ids_second, "Name": names_second})
# print(second)

names_third = ["Mike", "Dani", "Scott", "Josh", "Nate"]
ids_third = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
third = pd.DataFrame({"ID": ids_third, "Name": names_third})
# print(third)
for i in master['ID']:
    if i not in second["ID"]:
        print("NOT IN SECOND", i)
    if i not in third["ID"]:
        print("NOT IN THIRD", i)
```

OUTPUT ::

```
NOT IN SECOND 4
NOT IN SECOND 5
NOT IN THIRD 5
NOT IN SECOND 6
NOT IN THIRD 6
```

Why it says `NOT IN SECOND 6` and `NOT IN THIRD 5`?

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: is ID  index or column?

Comment: Likely a column given how it's referenced in the attempt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using `.isin` with `~` to filter `dataframes`. To compare with second you can use `master[~master.ID.isin(second.ID)]` and similar for third:

```
cmp_master_second, cmp_master_third = master[~master.ID.isin(second.ID)],  master[~master.ID.isin(third.ID)]

print(cmp_master_second)
print('\n-------- Seperate dataframes -----------\n')
print(cmp_master_third)
```

Result:

```
    Name
ID      
4   Josh
5   Nate

-------- Seperate dataframes -----------

     Name
ID       
6   Sandy
```

Comment: When I tried your code I got  `5   Nate` in the second dataframe. I have added the code in the main question about how I created my `master, second and third dataframes`.

Comment: @ShashankSingh Try now, I missed to add `ID` in third and instead added `index`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a `set` difference on the master and the other `DataFrame`s

```
In [315]: set(d1[0]) - set(d2[0])
Out[315]: {'Josh', 'Nate'}

In [316]: set(d1[0]) - set(d3[0])
Out[316]: {'Sandy'}
```