# How to iterate over rows between 2 different dataframes and capture the entire row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there way easier way to capture the difference in data between two dataframe. I am trying to compare 2 dataframe and find the missing. I found this attached link but it's not satisfying my requirement. In that post they comparing using Id but I wanted to compare the entire rows of 2 dataframes and find the mismatch row whether it is from A or B.

[Iterate over different dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50959624/iterate-over-different-dataframe)

DF 1:

```
country    from         to       flag
('GB',  'GB390065', 'GB66903',  'Y')
('FR',  'FR418458', 'FR765617', 'Y')
('FR',  'FR629810', 'FR855277', 'Y')
('FR',  'FR494010', 'FR332891', 'Y')
('FR',  'FR740500', 'FR907878', 'Y')
('FI',  'NB444135', 'NB234471', 'Y')
```

DF 2:

```
country    from         to       flag
('GB',  'GB390065', 'GB66903',  'Y')
('FR',  'FR418458', 'FR7656',   'Y')
('FR',  'FR629810', 'FR855277', 'Y')
('FR',  'FR4910',   'FR33891',  'Y')
('FR',  'FR740500', 'FR907878', 'Y')
('FI',  'NB444135', 'NB234471', 'Y')
```

My expected output:

```
country    from         to       flag   Available
('FR',  'FR418458', 'FR7656',   'Y'       df2)
('FR',  'FR4910',   'FR33891',  'Y'       df2)
```

The challenge I face here is `from column` and `to column` are same data only so when I tried using `merge function`, it is taking any one of the column and giving the result which is not meeting the requirement.

The output I got is

```
               country_code from_cust_id  ... to_cust_guid Merge_status
       322443         DE       DE180556  ...          NaN    left_only
       322444         DE        DE22191  ...          NaN    left_only
       322445         DE      DE2625168  ...          NaN    left_only
       322446         DE        DE17705  ...          NaN    left_only
       322447         DE      DE2556758  ...          NaN    left_only

      [5 rows x 7 columns]
              country_code from_cust_id  ... to_cust_guid Merge_status
       0                DE          NaN  ...     DE485137   right_only
       1                DE          NaN  ...     DE467209   right_only
       2                DE          NaN  ...     DE651068   right_only
       3                DE          NaN  ...     DE459729   right_only
       4                DE          NaN  ...     DE448683   right_only
```

Comment: You can concat and drop duplicates?

Comment: yes i tried that but i couldn't get the entire row of data and which df it is either A or B

Comment: posted the output which i got . Actually some of the data are only available in the left dataframe but in the output is showing as NaN for some columns@jezrael

Comment: check if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20225110/comparing-two-dataframes-and-getting-the-differences/20228113#20228113

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
df1['Available'] = 'df1'
df2['Available'] = 'df2'

available = pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates(subset=['from', 'to'], keep=False)
```

Comment: still i'm not getting the solution. Any help please@Vishnudev and @jezrael

Comment: @sumathi Please provide proper dataframes in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way you can do by converting dataframe to a set of tuples:

```
a1 = set(df1.apply(tuple,1).values)
a2 = set(df2.apply(tuple,1).values)

print(a1)

{('FI', 'NB444135', 'NB234471', 'Y'),
 ('FR', 'FR418458', 'FR765617', 'Y'),
 ('FR', 'FR494010', 'FR332891', 'Y'),
 ('FR', 'FR629810', 'FR855277', 'Y'),
 ('FR', 'FR740500', 'FR907878', 'Y'),
 ('GB', 'GB390065', 'GB66903', 'Y')}


print(a2)

{('FI', 'NB444135', 'NB234471', 'Y'),
 ('FR', 'FR418458', 'FR7656', 'Y'),
 ('FR', 'FR4910', 'FR33891', 'Y'),
 ('FR', 'FR629810', 'FR855277', 'Y'),
 ('FR', 'FR740500', 'FR907878', 'Y'),
 ('GB', 'GB390065', 'GB66903', 'Y')}

# now do set difference (in df2 not in df1)
diffs = pd.DataFrame(np.array([x for x in a2 - a1]))
diffs['Available'] = 'df2'

print(diffs)

    0         1        2  3 Available
0  FR  FR418458   FR7656  Y       df2
1  FR    FR4910  FR33891  Y       df2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(Mylist1,columns=['country','from','to','flag'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(Mylist2,columns=['country','from','to','flag'])
# print(df2)
indexes = (df1 != df2).any(axis=1)
indexes1 = (df2 != df1).any(axis=1)
df3 = df2.loc[indexes]
df4 = df1.loc[indexes1]
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
df3['Available'] = 'df1'
df4['Available'] = 'df2'
# print(df3)
# print(df4)
df_row_reindex = pd.concat([df3, df4], ignore_index=False)
print(df_row_reindex)


country from    to         flag Available
FR  FR418458    FR7656     Y    df1
FR  FR4910      FR33891    Y    df1
FR  FR418458    FR765617   Y    df2
FR  FR494010    FR332891   Y    df2
```